# How can I stop others from tagging me in unnecessary pictures?

Tags: facebook

This is a genuine problem in Facebook. I have been tagged by some unknown people in some pictures which are not related to me and surprisingly they are tagging me even in wallpapers easily searchabale at Google. So how can I stop people from tagging me?

Quite a time ago, I remember, I adjusted some settings resulting people not to tag me easily. Whenever they tried to tag me, a notification was sent to me and when I approved the request, then only I could be tagged. For some reason the setting is now disrupted. So please suggest me how can I restart the service?

Answer (score 1):

(All of this comes from Facebook help)

## [How can I turn off tag suggestions for photos of me?](https://www.facebook.com/help/187272841323203#How-can-I-turn-off-tag-suggestions-for-photos-of-me?)

To choose who sees suggestions to tag you in photos:

1. Click [image: settings gear] at the top right of any Facebook page and choose **Account Settings**
2. Click **Timeline and Tagging** from the left column
3. Under the **How can I manage tags people add and tagging suggestions?** section, click **Who sees tag suggestions when photos that look like you are uploaded?**
4. Select your preference from the dropdown menu

When you turn off tag suggestions, Facebook won’t suggest that people tag you when photos look like you. The template that we created to enable the tag suggestions feature will also be deleted. Note that friends will still be able to tag photos of you.

## [How do I remove a tag from a photo or post I’m tagged in?](https://www.facebook.com/help/140906109319589?sr=4&sid=0W31VZUV2CpNE6Jqw)

Hover over the story, click [image: pencil icon] and select **Report/Remove Tag** from the dropdown menu. You can then choose to remove the tag or ask the person who posted it to take it down.

You can also remove tags from multiple photos at once,

1. Go to your [activity log](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/289066827791446)
2. Click **Photos** in the left-hand column
3. Select the photos you'd like to remove a tag from
4. Click **Report/Remove Tags** at the top of the page
5. Click **Untag Photos** to confirm

Remember, when you remove a tag, that tag will no longer appear on the post or photo, but that post or photo is still visible to the audience it's shared with other places on Facebook, such as in News Feed and search.

Comment: I can't see "Who sees tag suggestions when photos that look like you are uploaded". Has Facebook changed?